# adding Spatial plugin to neo4j server

Tags: plugins, neo4j, spatial

I am having troubles with installing spatial plugin into neo4j server.

I am using neo4j 1.9.4 for Windows platform and spatial plugin from: http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/0.11-neo4j-1.9/ which I have in \plugin directory (c:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\plugin).

So when I am running the server and trying to get list of installed plugins:

```
GET http://localhost:7474/db/data
```

I am getting response:

```
{
  "extensions" : {
    "CypherPlugin" : {
      "execute_query" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query"
    },
    "GremlinPlugin" : {
      "execute_script" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script"
    }
  },
  "node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node",
  "reference_node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0",
  "node_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node",
  "relationship_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship",
  "extensions_info" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext",
  "relationship_types" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
  "batch" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch",
  "cypher" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
  "neo4j_version" : "1.9.4"
}
```

As you see, there is not spatial plugin in the list.
So far I didn't find any answer to my issue in the internet.

I'll be very thankful if you point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I used windows installer for neo4j, which seems doesnt work with plugins.
so I used the neo4j binaries which are working okay.

Comment: awesome. Couldn't think of that. And you don't finde this information anywhere in the docs.

Comment: Can tyou please be  more descriptive? Neo4j doesn't provide a binaries for a windows installation.

Comment: What he means is that you have to download the zip version for the windows installation and follow the instructions here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-installation.html  If you have problems try this troubleshooting manual: http://summerofphylet.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/neo4j-installation-guide/